# AngularJS custom order and limit

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting

I've list of items and need to sort them into lists by priority.

```
items = [
    {'type': 2, 'priority': 1, 'name': 'one'},
    {'type': 1, 'priority': 2, 'name': 'two'},
    {'type': 1, 'priority': 3, 'name': 'three'},
    {'type': 1, 'priority': 4, 'name': 'four'},
    {'type': 1, 'priority': 5, 'name': 'five'},
    {'type': 2, 'priority': 6, 'name': 'six'},
]
```

And I need to sort them with `ng-repeat` by priority, and separate by type. In one list max sum of `type` values should be 4. So output should look like (by `name`)

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
['five', 'six']
```

Comment: what is the question here exactly? or do you want us to do the work for you?

Comment: i've tried writing my own logic, but that not worked. Exactly don't know from what to start. And not asking to do everything for me, just point me on the right way.

Comment: arrange your data in the controller, use something like lodash to help you with manipulating your data https://lodash.com/

Answer (score 1):

With [Underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) you can try with:

```
var newItems = _.chain(items).sortBy('priority').groupBy('type').value();
```

And finally you can itinerate the new array in ng-repeat.

EDIT: Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wb5d5pfs/

Answer (score 1):

With a custom Angular [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter) you could filter your ng-repeat like in the demo below or here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/afpcsrr4/).

Instead of the `forEach` loop you could also use a lodash or underscore method (e.g. `groupBy('type'`).

With angular filters you could do it also like in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/g296ytj9/) and no custom filter required.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .filter('filterByType', TypeFilter)
    .value('MAX_ITEMS', 4) 
    .controller('mainController', MainController);

function TypeFilter($filter, MAX_ITEMS) {
    return function(input, selectedType) {
        var out = [], count=0,
            ordered = $filter('orderBy')(input, 'priority');
        //console.log("filter start", ordered);
        
        angular.forEach(ordered, function(obj, index) {
            if ( obj.type == selectedType.type && 
                count < MAX_ITEMS ) {
                out.push(obj);
                count++;
            }
        });
        //console.log(out);
        return out;
    }
}

TypeFilter.$inject = ['$filter', 'MAX_ITEMS'];

function MainController() {
    
    this.filterTypes = [
            {type: 1},
            {type: 2}
        ];
    this.type =  this.filterTypes[0];
    this.items = [
        {'type': 2, 'priority': 1, 'name': 'one'},
        {'type': 1, 'priority': 2, 'name': 'two'},
        {'type': 1, 'priority': 3, 'name': 'three'},
        {'type': 1, 'priority': 4, 'name': 'four'},
        {'type': 1, 'priority': 5, 'name': 'five'},
        {'type': 2, 'priority': 6, 'name': 'six'},
    ];
     
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
    Filter by type:
    <select ng-model="ctrl.type" ng-options="opt.type for opt in ctrl.filterTypes"></select>
    <p>selected type: {{ctrl.type.type}}</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items |filterByType:ctrl.type">
            {{item.name}}
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this one is good. But i wanted to split list by total num of type : 
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'] ; ['five', 'six']. I mean you looping items by priority and counting total type sum, while it's equal to 5, you should start making a new list.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood it correctly. But splitting the filtered data into more arrays could work like this. Please have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/g296ytj9/2/).